# Read mixed text file in MATLAB

Tags: string, matlab, text, filereader

I have a text file which contains numbers and characters, and, more importantly, it also has `*` which means repetition. For example:

```
data
-- comment
34*0.00 0.454 0.223 
0.544 5*4.866 
/
```

the above example starts with `34` , `zeros`, `0.00` , and then `0.454` and then `0.223` , then `0.544` and `5` of `4.866` repeated. which means it has `34 + 1 + 1 +1 + 5 = 42` numeric values. What is the best way to write a general code that can read such text files? Nothing else matters in the text file; only the numbers are relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first step is to read the data in. I'm assuming that the contents of your file look like this:

```
-- comment
34*0.00 0.454 0.223 
0.544 5*4.866
```

For that format, you can use [`textscan`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html) like so:

```
fid = fopen('data.txt');
data = textscan(fid, '%s', 'CommentStyle', '--');
fclose(fid);
data = data{1};
```

And `data` will look like this when displayed:

```
data =

  5×1 cell array

    '34*0.00'
    '0.454'
    '0.223'
    '0.544'
    '5*4.866'
```

Now, there are a few different ways you could try to convert this into numeric data of the format you need. One (potentially horrifying) way is to use [`regexprep`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexprep.html) like so:

```
>> data = regexprep(data, '([\d\.]+)\*([\d\.]+)', ...
                    '${repmat([$2 blanks(1)], 1, str2num($1))}')

data =

  5×1 cell array

    '0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.0…'
    '0.454'
    '0.223'
    '0.544'
    '4.866 4.866 4.866 4.866 4.866 '
```

As you can see, it replicates each string in place as needed. Now, we can convert each cell of the cell array to a numeric value and concatenate them all together like so, using [`cellfun`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html) and [`str2num`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2num.html):

```
>> num = cellfun(@str2num, data, 'UniformOutput', false);
>> num = [num{:}]

num =

  Columns 1 through 14

         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0

  Columns 15 through 28

         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0

  Columns 29 through 42

         0         0         0         0         0         0    0.4540    0.2230    0.5440    4.8660    4.8660    4.8660    4.8660    4.8660
```